What happens to running queries when I issue a rename statement in MySQL?
I'm running Mysql 8 with InnoDB tables. I have a table with 100k small rows that is under heavy-ish use (10-50 queries per second.
I want to swap the table with its newer version, using RENAME table TO old_table, replacement_table TO table. What happens to the running queries? Do they crash, or do they end gracefully? Do the new queries wait for the rename to end, or they can use the new version of the table, while existing queries complete with the old one?
In general, is it an OK approach to updating a table? I would need to compare every row for changes otherwise, look for new and deleted rows, so swapping a table like this seems to be way simpler.
Thanks

The RENAME statement needs to acquire a metadata lock on the table(s) being renamed, and so do the DML statements. As a result, the RENAME will wait for its turn to obtain the metadata lock, which is only possible when there are no running DML statements referencing this table, and while it is executing and holding the lock, other statements will wait. In other words, in-flight statements will complete before RENAME begins, and other statements will wait until RENAME completes.
Reference
